# Use python environment as an Artifact in Azure pipelines

Tags: python-3.x, yaml, azure-pipelines, virtual-environment

so I´m trying to create a python environment in az pipelines and publish as an artifact in order to use it across jobs. I can publish the artifact, also it is downloaded in next job, problem I have is that seems that "environment/bin/activate" doesn´t work, what am I doing wrong? is there another way to achieve that?

build and publish artifact

```
jobs:
  - job: BuildPythonArtifact
    workspace:
      clean: all
    pool:
      vmImage: $(UBUNTU_DEFAULT_VERSION)
    steps:
      - task: UsePythonVersion@0
        inputs:
          versionSpec: "3.9"
          displayName: "Use Python 3.9"

      - script: |
          python -m venv env
          source env/bin/activate
          python -m pip install --upgrade pip
          pip install -r requirements.txt
        workingDirectory: $(Build.SourcesDirectory)
        displayName: "Install requirements"

      - task: PublishPipelineArtifact@1
        inputs:
          targetPath: $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/env
          artifactName: pythonenv
```

download artifact

```
    steps:
      - task: UsePythonVersion@0
        inputs:
          versionSpec: "3.9"
          displayName: "Use Python 3.9"

      - task: DownloadPipelineArtifact@2
        inputs:
          artifact: pythonenv

      - script: |
          source $(Pipeline.Workspace)/bin/activate
```

files are there, bit seems that it ignores the env activate

[image]

What I expect is to can activate or reuse python env to avoid installing requirements in every job

Comment: Look at your folder structure. `DownloadPipelineArtifact` downloads to a specific working folder, and `$(Pipeline.Workspace)/bin/activate` isn't it.

Comment: Hi @DanielMann, sorry to answer such late, I really tried your solution but azure doesn´t want to activate the environment if is an artifact, at the end, I put all things under same job, but I,m investigating how to use conda environment, seems like a native solution